# What are some special trading phenomena that would be interesting to research?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies

I'm looking to research special trading phenomena like end-of-month bonds activity, daily closing imbalances in cash equities, futures expiration/settlement manipulation (like in VIX) etc. What are some other interesting phenomena? I have access to all kinds of hft data so that won't be a problem.

Comment: if you have access to HF data, how to calculate and use (eg, annualize from different frequencies) intraday volatility could be interesting (and useful).  It has real-world implications and is very much an unclosed case.